# How can I see a login's default database?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I need to detect a login's default database. Which system table/view should I query for that in SQL Server 2005?

Answer (score 5):

The master.sys.syslogins view is provided for [backward compatibility and will be removed in future](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178593.aspx). You should use [sys.server_principals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188786.aspx) view and the column default_database_name.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to get this information for a specific login using sp_helplogins.